# Response data Assertion error not shown in Jmeter Dashboard

Tags: jmeter

I have generated the Jmeter Dashboard result and it shows me the success and failure, but I need the specific failure to be shown in the dashboard, the reason why the test fails as we check in the GUI. Is it possible to get a detailed error based on failure in the dashboard?

[image: Jmeter GUI Error]
[image: Jmeter Dashboard Error]

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect with some screenshot ? Thanks

Comment: I have provided the screenshots, In dashboard the actual and expected error is not shown, it shows the test is failed. I need to have the actual and expected

Comment: What version of jmeter are you using ?

Comment: I am using Jmeter 4.0

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

From what you show the dashboard shows the Assertion failure message in first column.

If you want details you can use Custom Failure message of [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to put more details:

[image: Custom Failure Message]